# proper -- can this postpositive adjective be substituted for "in and of itself"?

Tags: meaning, postpositive-adjectives

Example:

> In computer programming, a directive pragma (from "pragmatic") is a language construct that specifies how a compiler (or assembler or interpreter) should process its input. Directives are not part of the language **proper** – they are not part of the grammar, and may vary from compiler to compiler – but instead function either as an in-band form of a command-line option, specifying compiler behavior, or are processed by a preprocessor.

Is it alright to understand the word **proper** when used as a postpositive adjective as the expression **in and of itself**?

Comment: What's wrong with the simple yet effective _'itself'_ ?

Comment: There are actual several dictionaries online [including this one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/proper) that give a specific definition for proper when it occurs after the noun. Which dictionaries have you consulted? What did you not understand about the postpositive definition?

Comment: _In and of itself_ is similar, but not quite right; using this here would imply the directives are only partially part of the language. Instead, _proper_ means _in the strictest sense_. This sentence is not saying the directives are only partially part of the language, it is a statement that when you interpret _part of the language_ strictly, the directives are _not_ part of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those phrases are used to distinguish between a core concept or object and other things that may be linked to it, but they are used to eliminate different things.

**The expression "*X proper*" means "the true X" or "the core X".** It is used to distinguish between an object and something else that is either very similar, or very closely linked to it.

For example, one might refer to *London proper* to mean the area that is officially designated as part of the city, as opposed to *Greater London*, which is the whole urban area that has built up around it.

Or, as Omnidisciplinarianist mentions: a wolf may not be a dog proper, but it still looks and acts a lot like one.

**The expression "*X in and of itself*", on the other hand, means "X, without assistance from anything else".** It is used to distinguish between something that is complete, and things that need something else added.

An engine is not a motorbike in and of itself, but it's still a very important part of one.

This nutrient paste is a complete diet in and of itself - you don't need to add anything else to stay healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:

**No**

Long Answer:

The expression ***in and of itself*** is defined by both the [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+and+of+itself) and [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in%20and%20of%20itself?s=t) to mean either *intrinsically* or *considered alone*. Neither of these definitions are "close" to the definition of *proper* in this context (which is, as CarSmack links and Aes states, *in the strict[est] sense* or *in its true[st] form*).

If it helps, the following two are common examples of where you'll see the phrase used:

1. ***Closely related to, and having a number of X-like qualities, but not actually an X*** 
    A gray wolf may not be a dog *[in the strictest sense of the word]*, but it still looks like and acts much like a Husky, which is.
2. ***In the process of becoming an X, especially if nearly complete*** 
    A trained medical professional with a degree whom is currently undergoing a period of supervised practice isn't a doctor *[in the truest sense of the word]* in the United States of America until that period is completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

May be this could be helpful.

I've often corrected people around me, here in India. Let's take this conversation as an example.

> Where do you live, Anand? ~ I live in Mumbai 
>  
>   Oh! ***Proper Mumbai?*** ~ No! ***Mumbai proper.***

When placed *before noun,* it serves as an adjective meaning [*suitable for the purpose/reason or something real*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/proper).

But when it's placed *after noun*, it means *'main'* or something *core*.

Having said this,

> Directives are not part of the ***language proper***....

means *directives* aren't the *core/main* part of the language and thus, it varies from a compiler to compiler.